# Find current in a transistor with the base connected to the collector

Tags: microcontroller

For the circuit shown in Figure, calculate the emitter current intensity of
transistor, knowing that VEB = 0.84 V, β = 100.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be an academic question and does not display an attempt at solution.

Answer (score 2):

1st pass (good approximation):

Assume that the voltage across R1 is negligible because the base current is so low.

Voltage across R2 = supply voltage minus VEB = 15 - 0.84 = 14.16 V.

Current through R2 = voltage / resistance = 14.16 V / 470 Ω = 30.1 mA.

---

Second pass (more accurate):

Current through R1 = collector current / Beta = 30 mA / 100 = 100 µA

Voltage across R1 = resistance * current = 1 kΩ * 100 µA = 100 mV.

Voltage across R2 = supply voltage minus VEB  minus R1 voltage = 15 - 0.84 - 0.1 = 14.06 V.

Current through R2 = voltage / resistance = 14.06 V / 470 Ω = 29.9 mA.

So, the more accurate answer is within 0.5 % of the first answer. That's 10 times less than the tolerance in the value of the 470 Ω resistor (5 %). Therefore, the first answer was plenty good. There was no need to do a second pass.

Comment: With a simulation [here](https://tinyurl.com/ysge9r9q).

Comment: Thank you so much